# how to connect database to my desktop application while both are placed in different system?

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a desktop application in c# and database in microsoft sql server. so I want to get to know about my problem i.e. is it possible that database and desktop application can be placed in different pc and windows authentication or sql server authentication should i use to make a database for that application?

Comment: yes its possible you need to create firewall inbound rules on database server with port 1433 and for port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is ok.for this, you need to config your connection string in desktop application
as follows:

```
Data Source=(your sql server instance name);Initial Catalog=your db name;User ID=username;Password=password
```

and then config sql server port on remote computer's firewall.
[this link](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Docs-v1.1.2/GUID-CF5C89EA-0918-4002-8391-80CBEDE0BB5E)

Note:for remote connection to your sql server instance ,you should change security of sql server instance to 'sql server and windows Auth' mode.